# Trouble intercepting NFC intents with my app

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

Here is my intent-filter code...

```
<activity android:name="IntentReceiver">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

        <data
          android:scheme="http"
          android:host="mytix.com"
          android:pathPattern="/" />

        <data
            android:scheme="http"
            android:host="www.mytix.com"
            android:pathPattern="/" />

      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

What I want to do is intercept any NFC tags which have a url data type and the url is pointing to http://mytix.com (or http://www.mytix.com).

However the above code doesn't seem to work. Instead my NFC tags just open the browser and go the url in question (which is the right url! :) I've checked).

How do I intercept the intent? What I want to end up with is a tag that will take users to the mobile website if they don't have the app, but if they have the app installed it will take them straight to the app. I believe I am on the right lines, but the code above doesn't work for some reason.

I'm installing the app by building straight to the phone from Eclipse btw - does this make a difference?

Thanks

Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I want to do is intercept any NFC tags which have a url data type and the url is pointing to http://mytix.com (or http://www.mytix.com).

Try `NDEF_DISCOVERED`, not `TAG_DISCOVERED`. Android will only support direct launches like this for NDEF-formatted NFC tags. If your NFC tag is using something else, you can't use the `<intent-filter>` AFAIK, but rather would have to parse the data out yourself.

[Here is a book sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/NFC/URLTagger) that demonstrates writing a URL to an NDEF-formatted tag (triggered via the Share Page option in a browser app) and responding to NDEF-formatted tags with a specific URL written to them.

Comment: Thanks for that. For some reason copying the intent-filter code out of your manifest in your book sample project worked brilliantly. I've been through each and every iteration of TAG_DISCOVERED, NDEF_DISCOVERED - every action and category and all sorts but yours seems to work fine.